# Searching In QTableWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I've tried adding a search function on my QTableWidget on my own because the tutorials on google are either related to c++ or pyqt4. Now I know there's an easier way if I change it to QTableView so I'm down to change it if there's no other choice.

Here's my solution so far.

```
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.table = QTableWidget(self)
        self.search = QLineEdit(self)
        self.table.setColumnCount(2)

        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem('Name'))
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem('Age'))

        people = {'Bob': '43', 'Jeff': '22', 'Juan': '30'}
        self.table.setRowCount(len(people))
        for num, name in enumerate(people):
            name = QTableWidgetItem(name)
            age = QTableWidgetItem(people[name])
            
            self.table.setItem(num, 0, name)
            self.table.setItem(num, 1, age)
        
        self.search.textChanged.connect(self.findName)
    
    def findName(self):
        name_to_find = self.search.text()
        table_rows = self.table.rowCount()
        if table_rows != 0 and len(name) != 0:
            for row in range(self.table.rowCount()):
                if name_to_find not in self.table.item(row, 0).text():
                    self.table.hideRow(row)
        else:
            for row in range(table_rows):
                self.table.showRow(row)
```

There's two problems (that I know) in this.

1. `if name != self.table.item(row, 0).text()` is too literal so I have to change it to:
   `if name.lower() != self.table.item(row, 0).text().lower()`
2. (Important). Is that it doesn't detect backspace it does but when I backspace to a specific moment where multiple rows were shown I can't see them because the the function already hid them . So for example I write 'jeff' in the lineedit and backspaced until j. it doesn't show juan. I'd have to clear the lineedit first for everything to show up. A solution I thought of was adding a showRow function. (just thought of this as I'm writing and I'll try this as soon as I'm finished)

Anyways the main purpose of this post is to find a better way of searching a QTableWidget so I need the answer to this not my solution. But if you guys have a solution for mine you could also comment it so I can get a breath of relief.

An alternate idea of mine is highlighting the row (change the background color) but in the case of 100 poeple it'd be hard to fnd the highlight. a solution is to scroll to the item (.scrollToItem()) but if the user doesn't know the full name and knows only the 'J' part. where will it scroll to since there are multiple J's.

Comment: While a search like that might be effective for very small models, I'd suggest you to find other solutions, such as using a QSortFilterProxyModel, as using hiding/showing rows is usually not a good idea for filtering. Btw, I had to remove the last paragraph in the post, as in SO asking for tutorials/howtos is considered off topic, and greetings are normally removed.

Comment: Also, be more careful with your examples: in the code above, you're overwriting the `name` variable of the for loop, and the result is that then it tries to access the people dictionary using a QTableWidgetItem as a key, which not only doesn't exists in the dictionary, but will also probably make the program crash, as those objects are not hashable. Also, the last for loop is using an undeclared `count` variable (which obviously was the table row count).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While hiding and showing rows can be fine for small data models, it requires some care and attention, otherwise it usually creates some logic issues just like yours. For future reference, consider using a [QSortFilterProxyModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html).

The problem is that you are just hiding the rows whenever the "search query" matches the items, but you don't restore other rows back if they were, since you only do that when the query is empty.

The solution is pretty simple: instead of `showRow()`/`hideRow()`, use [`setRowHidden`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#setRowHidden), with the `hide` parameter based on the *negative* match:

```
    def findName(self):
        name = self.search.text().lower()
        for row in range(self.table.rowCount()):
            item = self.table.item(row, 0)
            # if the search is *not* in the item's text *do not hide* the row
            self.table.setRowHidden(row, name not in item.text().lower())
```

<sub>An unrelated note: always prefer layout managers; while yours is just a simple example, having UI elements overlapping like that is not a good thing (it's kind of disorienting and annoying, even for a basic code example: for instance, the window shows up very small, when it's resized the table keeps its small size, and the headers are not visible because they're hidden by the QLineEdit). Creating good questions also includes creating good results with the provided code: a simple QVBoxLayout would have sufficed and would have made your question even better.</sub>

Comment: Hello @musicamante, how about if it's a MySQL large database of thousands of records. What would be the best way to filter the data on the table? Do I do it via SQL QUERY or FILTER THE ITEMS loaded on the TABLE WIDGET?

Comment: @lloydyu24 Use QTableView with either a QSortFilterProxyModel used for a QSqlTableModel, or a QSqlQueryModel.

Comment: I hate to disturb anyone here but I can't find anything on my inquiry on the internet. Thank you!

Comment: @lloydyu24 sorry, but since what you're asking is off topic, we shouldn't use comments for this answer. You have to study how the QtSql module and its classes work, and read about QSortFilterProxyModel in the documentation. It's not something you can do in a few minutes, so start from there with patience: the Qt documentation is extensive but well written. If you still don't understand how to use them, then create a new question.

Comment: Your answer is enough to get me started already on the right path. I don't want to ask more. Before your answer, I didn't which way to go. Thank you sir!